# Textbook recommendation for multiple traveling salesman problem transformation to standard TSP

Tags: reference-request, traveling-salesman

I am looking for a good textbook explaining:

"Transformation of Multiple Traveling Salesmen Problem to the Standard Traveling Salesman Problem."

Comment: You might be asking for too much by asking for a textbook that explains every step in detail. This is the sort of transformation that textbooks might expect you to figure out based on other information you learn about similar or simpler transformations. Similarly, you might consider trying to do the transformation yourself and then post here to ask a more specific question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

The transformation is mentioned in Ahuja, Magnanti, and Orlin, *Network Flows*, Exercise 16.25(b).

Comment: which chapter and page number?

Comment: but I am looking for a textbook explaining it in detail and an easy-to-follow manner.

Comment: https://mitmgmtfaculty.mit.edu/jorlin/solution-manual/

Comment: thank you but  it is hard to follow the very short solution. I need  good textbook explaining every step.